# How to prove that $4a^4-4a^3+5a^2-4a+1\ge 0$ for all real values of $a$?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math

Preferably not using calculus.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: @Masacroso : I'm able to prove it when a>1 and when a<0 by using factorization.

Comment: Can you show your factorisation ?

Comment: Hint: $(2a-1)^2 = 4a^2-4a+1$ and $1+4 = 5$

Comment: You can factor it as $(2x-1)^2(x^2+1)$, and the first term is greater than or equal to 0 since it's a square, and the second is greater than 0 because  it's one plus a square. Then their product is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: OK. I got the answer.
4a^4-4a^3+5a^2-4a+1=(a^2+1)(4a^2-4a+1)>=0

Comment: Easy questions always get to be answered first :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align}
4a^4-4a^3+5a^2-4a+1 &=4a^4-4a^3+a^2+4a^2-4a+1\\&=(2a-1)^2a^2+(2a-1)^2
\end{align}